# Prevent radio selections from overlapping time selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with event selections, these are radio options with a value that holds date and time like so:

Thursday Oct/31 | 1:00 PM - 3:15 PM

The problem is that there are several events that are overlapping in time and the user completing the form is not allowed to select overlapping times. What I need to accomplish is when an overlapping of times occurs to give all options that are in conflict with eachother a red background. I have been experimenting with jQuery but am unable to come up with a solution. So far I have this:

All radio options have the .time class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var map = {};
    $(".time").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        map[$(this).attr('name')] = value;
        $(".time").each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                time = $(this).val();
                tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                $.each(map, function(key, val) {
                    if (val == time) {
                        tr.addClass('red');
                    } else {
                        tr.removeClass('red');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The above does not work the way I wanted it to, in fact it does not work at all as expected. If someone can shed a light I would appreciate that a lot.

Comment: Yes, the fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/gnQqe/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".time").change(function() {
        var values = $("input.time").map(function(){
            return $(this).val();
        });
        values.each( function (){
            var overlapping = $("input.time[value='"+ this +"']");
            if (overlapping.filter(":checked").length > 1){                            
                overlapping.parents("tr").addClass("red");}
            else{
                overlapping.parents("tr").removeClass("red");
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

It first maps all radio button values, then according to the checked count for each value adds/removes the respective red class.

http://jsfiddle.net/4rJTR/

Comment: Exactly what I needed, much appreciation for your effort!